# Velocity between old and new position

Tags: c++, math, vector, velocity

Im something here saw post with getting velocity by saving old pos for UNITY, some code:

```
void TestVelocity(Vector3& Pos, Vector3 &Result)
{
    Vector3 PreviousPos;

    if (GetTickCount() >= velupd)
    {
        velupd = GetTickCount() + 100//random timer for test;

        Vector3 Diff = Pos - PreviousPos;
        float Len = sqrtf(Diff .x * Diff .x + Diff .y * Diff .y + Diff .z * Diff .z);

        if (Len >= 0.01)
        {
            Result = (Diff / Len);
        }
    }
      PreviousPos = Pos.
}
```

It calculates wrong. Data aviable only object position (no speed and etc).

Comment: What value do you get for what data and what value do you expect for what variable?

Comment: `PreviousPos` isn't being initialized before doing the calculation.

Comment: This should be output as Vector3 velocity between new object position and old position. Or what you mean?

Comment: It looks like probably `PreviousPos` ought to be `static`...

Comment: Other part corrects excluding to move PreviousPos to globals vars?

Comment: `Len` is how far it's moved. Shouldn't it be `Len/(NewTickCount-OldTickCount)` to get the speed?

Comment: I wouldn't make `PreviousPos` a global variable.  Instead I would make it a function parameter and make it the responsibility of the caller to keep track of the 2 points it wants the speed calculated from.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking in your last comment, but be aware that `PreviousPos` is either reinitialized to (0,0,0) or not initialized at all (undetermined values) (depending on how `Vector3` is implemented) each time you enter the `TestVelocity` function.

Comment: Just enough move TestVelocity in globals variables. Idk about @TedLyngmo post, im not pro in math so thats why im asking here heh

Comment: `m/s`, `mph` etc. are all examples of speed. Distance covered/time units. Here you have: `len/tick`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No. Im need not exatct speed value. Just velocity vector in Result.

Comment: You are using PReviousPos before it's initialized here: `Vector3 Diff = Pos - PreviousPos;`

Answer (score 1):

It would require more details to give you a more accurate answer. But I see basically two problems. You are not initializing the **PreviousPos** object and it seems to me that you want it to persist, right?

Assuming that the **Vector3** class has the minus (**-**) operator overload, so you can do this operation, you might do this.

```
void TestVelocity(Vector3& Pos, Vector3 &Result)
{  
static Vector3 PreviousPos; //Initialize here the initial position to zero with your constructor

    if (GetTickCount() >= velupd)
    {
        velupd = GetTickCount() + 100//random timer for test;

        Vector3 Diff = Pos - PreviousPos;
        float Len = sqrtf(Diff .x * Diff .x + Diff .y * Diff .y + Diff .z * Diff .z);

        if (Len >= 0.01)
        {
            Result = (Diff / Len);
        }
    }
  PreviousPos = Pos.
}
```

Another solution would be to take the previous position as an argument, but as I said, its hard to tell if we don't know what is the implementation you desire. These are **suggestions** based on what appears to be needed.

Comment: Im edited my code, seems smth works. Ofcource oldpos should be saved every velupd tick.